# Error DataTables PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

Hola a todos intento usar dataTables con Php, apartir de datos de Mysql, pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> DataTables warning table id=example1-Request unknown parameter  '0' for row 0

Este es mi codigo

```
          <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Clave</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
              <th>Apellido Materno</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <?php
              $query="select * from directores";
              $sql=mysqli_query($cn,$query);
              $total=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row['clave'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['apepat'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['apemat'];?></td>
                </tr>
                  <?php
                }
              ?>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>


   <script src="../../plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../../plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
   $(function () {
   $("#example1").DataTable({
   "language": {
                "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                "sUrl":            "",
                "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst":    "Primero",
                    "sLast":     "Último",
                    "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            }

      });
      });
   </script>
```

Me muestra de manera correcta los datos
[image: Ejemplo]
, pero al hacer el load de la pagina me muestra el error descrito arriba.

Comment: notaste que tienes tus `tr` dentro de un `tr`?

Comment: mmmm no puedo creer.... no me habia dado cuenta, muchas gracias por la observacion ahora el codigo funciona

Comment: no se si sea bien visto por la comunidad que escribas tu comentario como respuesta para aceptarla.

Comment: ok, voy a ponerlo como respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error se produce porque declaras un elemento `tr` y luego generas muchos `tr` dentro de él.

Donde dice:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <?php
      $query="select * from directores";
      $sql=mysqli_query($cn,$query);
      $total=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
    ?>
       <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['clave'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['apepat'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['apemat'];?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php
            }
    ?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Debiese decir:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
      $query="select * from directores";
      $sql=mysqli_query($cn,$query);
      $total=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
    ?>
       <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['clave'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['apepat'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['apemat'];?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php
            }
    ?>
</tbody>
```